# Java, checking elements of an ArrayList whether they implements an interface

Tags: java, class, arraylist, interface

I have many classes and some of them implements interfaces, and I have an ArrayList contains some objects created from those classes. How can I make them checked if they implement any interface?

Comment: The `instanceof` operator works with interface types, but before you jump on that, why don't you know already?  If it is important that the elements of your list implement a particular interface, then the list's type parameter should enforce that.

Comment: Oh I got the point, thanks a lot..

Comment: As Bollinger commented… If `Cat` and `Dog` classes implement `Animal` interface, then: `List< Animal > animals = List.of( new Dog( "Rover" ) , new Cat( "Fluffy" ) ) ;`